# Is it possible to mock a closure using GroovyMock?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-2.0

So I have a utility class for validation with static methods like the following:

```
static validateX = { x ->
    // some business logc
}
```

Now, I use this static closure in my command objects for custom validation:

```
class TestCommand {
     String x

     static constraints = {
         x(validator: Utility.validateX)
     }
}
```

The problem arises when I try to mock this custom validator during my unit tests. I have tried a bunch of things as seen below:

```
GroovyMock(Utility)
Utility.validateX(someVal) >> true
Utility.validateX.call(someVal) >> true
Utility.validateX >> { def x -> true }
```

But none of these work!

I have found a work around where I change static utility closure to a method. When I change it to a normal method, GroovyMock seems to work fine. But I would rather not do this since I'll then I have to use the ampersand symbol wherever I reference the method, and I can see it confusing others on my team.

So basically, my question is how do I mock a static closure in my unit tests?

Comment: try to mock getValidateX method. Also if you can save without validation you can do that like: .save(validate:false); If both will not work for you, so that you should play with Proxy

Comment: Is it possible to mock just the static method? Are you saying I should do `GroovyMock(validateX)`? Additionally, the validate method on the command object is called automatically by Grails since it's a parameter of the controller method.

Comment: @Koloritnij unfortunately, mocking validateX does not seem to work either. Could you expand on the proxy comment?

Comment: I'd never work with that, so it's just a think :) https://www.baeldung.com/java-dynamic-proxies it's something like a Mock but with more control, at least I suggest you to google in that way

Comment: What is your intent? Are you trying to get a domain object saved with circumventing the validation or are you trying something different?